# How to i check if users name has already been entered

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I would like avoid asking a users name if it has already been entered earlier in the conversation. How do I set a condition to check if context variable 'sys-person' is empty/null?

Answer (score 2):

Watson Conversation has Context variables to you save what you need in your Dialog flow.

> The dialog is stateless, meaning that it does not retain information
>   from one interchange with the user to the next. Your application is
>   responsible for maintaining any continuing information that it needs.
>   However, the application can pass information to the dialog, and the
>   dialog can update this information and pass it back to the
>   application. It does so by using `context variables`.
>
> A `context variable` is a variable that you define in a node, and
>   optionally specify a default value for. Other nodes or application
>   logic can subsequently set or change the value of the `context`
>   `variable` (like: context.variableName = "Jon").
>
> You can *condition* against `context` `variable` values by **referencing** a
>   context variable from a **dialog node condition** to determine whether to
>   execute a node. And you can reference a `context variable` from dialog
>   node response conditions to show different reponses depending on a
>   value provided by an external service or by the user.

So, you can simple save the name in one context variable, like:

```
{
  "context": {
    "nameHere": "<? @sys-person ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Your name is $nameHere."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

And you can access this context variable using `$nameHere`. In my JSON example [Advanced JSON] I show one form to you check it.

- See the Official Documentation about Context variables [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#context).

Comment: thanks for that Sayuri. I need to check whether the user has already entered his/her name earlier in the conversation in another node.. so I need to set a condition to check if the context variable -sys-name is empty.. if its empty "whats you name" if in has content "hi 'Jon' ..." how do I set such a condition?

Comment: Please **mark** the question following the [Stackoverflow Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). And, answering your question, you can just create one condition with `if bot recognizes $nameHere response: your name is $nameHere?` and, you can use `!` for negative conditions, `if bot recognizes !$nameHere response: please type your name`... If you want more information, please ask a new question and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sayuri, create a context variable for user name and check for this context variable in dialog,

In dialog you can use,

`if $nameHere:
     then:
    your response`

If this is mandatory variable then using slots would also be choice, which can check and ask for user name in single node